# Keyboarding in Intellij Dialogs having number of issues in Mac

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

There seems to be a a series of problems related to using the keyboard (only) on the mac - as opposed to resorting to the mouse.  I am wondering if people have figured out workarounds for some of these issues.

[image: Example 1: Hitting Enter does not work. Hitting tab does not work.Hitting space does not work. Only way to 'accept'/close the dialog is to mouse over and hit ok. Yuck.]

[image: Example 2: Using The Option button we can the "Do Refactor has D underlined - so clicking option-D should accept. However it does not work. Once again - only way is to click using the mouse]

[image]
 [image: Example 3: In ANY open file dialog you have to type in manually the entire path. This one is confirmed bug by JetBrains, and I wonder if anyone has an idea of workaround]

Example 1: Hitting Enter does not work. Hitting tab does not work.Hitting space does not work. Only way to 'accept'/close the dialog is to mouse over and hit ok. Yuck.

Example 2: Using The Option button we can the "Do Refactor has D underlined - so clicking option-D should accept. However it does not work. Once again - only way is to click using the mouse

Example 3:  In refactor dialog, one can not hit "return" or tab over or use "alt-r" to accept the Refactor. Once again - using mouse is the only way.

Example 4: In ANY open file dialog you have to type in manually the entire path. This one is confirmed bug by JetBrains, and I wonder if anyone has an idea of workaround

Comment: Can you reproduce 1,2,3 with the default installation, Mac OS X 10.5+ keymap, no third-party plug-ins and the default Mac Look&Feel in Preferences | Appearance? To try it with the defaults remove/rename [config/system/plugins folders](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108).

Comment: That is too much to ask to do when in middle of a project. However, when I decide to upgrade to IJ13 let's see if this persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the "option" key and the Mnemonics DO show up. I discovered this by accident.